# Is there a way to make PyCharm to code complete CDN loaded libraries?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ide, pycharm, cdn

I am currently building Django App and I just loaded needed libraries from https://www.jsdelivr.com/

It's `Bootstrap`, `jQuery` and few other JS libs, but might grow in the future.

My question is can I somehow get completion and IntelliSense working without loading files locally to `STATIC` folder. Just by using CDN `PyCharm` does not seem to have any idea of `Bootstrap` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm has a built-in capability to download CDN libraries to local files.

Just press Alt + Enter (Mac) or press yellow lightbulb in front of the CDN URL to make local copies of the CDN files.

This gives you IntelliSense on these files and class names (like bootstrap or jQuery).

Doing this does not actually load the files in the project but outside and creates links in your idea/{project}.iml file example for my project below -->

```
+    <orderEntry type="library" name="bootstrap" level="application" />
+    <orderEntry type="library" name="tether" level="application" />
+    <orderEntry type="library" name="jquery" level="application" />
```

Comment: Not seeing any option to "make local copies" among the Context Actions. Do you recall where your URL was when you invoked the yellow-lightbulb help? My URL is in Python code, where PyCharm recognizes it as a URL, but it may not recognize it as a jsdelivr module.